# Are the classical epics on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, mythology

Do the classical epics *Iliad*, *Odyssey* and the *Aeneid* come under the scope of SFF?
And *Metamorphoses*, of course.

They involve fantasy by today's standards, but does it make a difference whether they were conceived by the author as fantasy or not?

I don't see them being discussed on this site, and I also don't see any other SE site relevant to asking questions about them. It would be great to have questions about them here, as there are lots and lots to be asked about them.

I see the oncoming objection that this would be opening a can of worms, but Divine Comedy, Paradise Lost and Indian epics should be called religious epics, and not fantasy. Pharsalia is purely historic.

Put simply, do we classify mythical fiction as fantasy?

Comment: Let me know if that linked question doesn't totally answer yours.  I think it covers it.

Comment: @Keen Thank you, it does cover the topic, but looks like no definite answer is given as to the question of classical epics per se. Religious works I'm sure should be excluded , but asteri claims that there are a handful people who apparently believe in the Hellenic religion! Then the question goes to whether the classical epics form the primary source of this religion (as we ban only primary sources). The wiki page is silent on this, but a bit of search showed that they are indeed the primary sources (along with the Orphic hymns and Theogony.

Comment: @Keen However there is one question by DVK on Greek mythology linked there which has a good standing. So should I try my hand by asking one of my questions?

Comment: Go for it.  Worst case, it'll get closed.

Comment: @Keen OK. Any idea what happened to that Area 51 proposal for Mythology?

Comment: It's still there, or at least *a* Mythology proposal is there.